# Loop through an object and extract elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm looping through object to extract firstName, lastName values and return an array that houses number of objects

here is desired output

```
let result = [ {firstName: 'Art', lastName: 'Blakey'},
    {firstName: 'Jimmy', lastName: 'Cobb'},
    {firstName: 'Elvin', lastName: 'Jones'},
    {firstName: 'Max', lastName: 'Roach'},
    {firstName: 'Tony', lastName: 'Williams'}];
```

Here is the source object

```
src = {
_id: "QdKbM9S55qHxuT7vA"
firstname: "John"
lastname: "Doe"
},
_id: "QdKbM9S55qHxuT7vA"
firstname: "Jane"
lastname: "Doe"
},
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
let myData = [];

_handleSearch() {

  src.map((user) => {
    myData.push({
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname
    })
  })
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, the result is number of nested objects unlike the desired output

Comment: `src` object doesn't look like valid object. Show the correct code

Comment: can you show us the output you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change `src`, it is not proper, `object` values should be separated by `,`. Check this:

```js
src = [{
          _id: "QdKbM9S55qHxuT7vA",
          firstname: "John",
          lastname: "Doe"
       },{
          _id: "QdKbM9S55qHxuT7vA",
          firstname: "Jane",
          lastname: "Doe"
       },{
          _id: "QdKbM9S55qHxuT7vA",
          firstname: "Jane",
          lastname: "Doe"
      }]

let result = src.map((item)=>{
      return {firstname: item.firstname, lastname: item.lastname}
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let myData = [];

_handleSearch() {

  myData = src.map((user) => {
    return {
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname
    }
  })
```